# Counting the numbers of lines of data as it comes in?

Tags: wc

I am currently connected to the Twitter Stream, and I would like to count the number of lines of data as they come in.  I know I can do `wc-l` to just count the lines, but I want it to be auto-updating.  Kind of like how `tail -F` works, but instead, I want a running tally of how many records I've received.

Is there a simple command to do this in UNIX?

Comment: (the difference being that the other question asked for a GNU solution while this one asks for a Unix one, but the accepted answer here is Linux specific, while the one there is POSIX (so GNU, Unix and _Linux_ compatible)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`watch` can be used to repatedly run a command.  The `-n` option specifies the time in seconds that the command is repeated.  Commands that include pipes need to be quoted

```
$ watch -n1 'wc -l < twitter.stream'
```